# Login with Facebook doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, facebook

I try to make login with Facebook but it still doesn't work. The problem is that after the user logs in, it doesn't redirect in another page and it isn't store facebook account in a mysql database. Please, could you give me some advice hot to fix it?

link: www.quatsch.cz

Thanks in advance.

```
<?php
include "connect.php";
require 'facebook/src/facebook.php';
require 'fb_config.php';

// Get User ID
$user = $facebook->getUser();


if($user)
{
  try 
  {
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
  } 
  catch (FacebookApiException $e) 
  {
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
  }
}

if($user)
{
  $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl(array('next'=>'http://127.0.0.1:8080/fb/fb_logout.php'));
}
else
{
  $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array( 'scope' => 'email, user_birthday, user_about_me, user_hometown, user_location, user_photos, friends_photos'));
  echo '<a href="'.$loginUrl.'"><img src="images/facebook.png" title="Login with Facebook" /></a>';
}



if($user)
{
  mysql_query("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS fb_users
                (
                id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
                date DATETIME,
                facebook_id VARCHAR(50),
                username VARCHAR(200),
                name VARCHAR(200),
                email VARCHAR(200),
                gender VARCHAR(10),
                birthday VARCHAR(50),
                location VARCHAR(200),
                hometown VARCHAR(200),
                bio TEXT,
                timezone VARCHAR(10),
                access_token TEXT
                )");


  $fb_info = $user_profile; 

  $date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
  $facebook_id = mysql_real_escape_string($fb_info['id']);
  $username = mysql_real_escape_string($fb_info['username']);
  $name = mysql_real_escape_string($fb_info['name']);
  $email = mysql_real_escape_string($fb_info['email']);
  $gender = mysql_real_escape_string($fb_info['gender']);
  $birthday = mysql_real_escape_string($fb_info['birthday']);
  $location = mysql_real_escape_string($fb_info['location']['name']);
  $hometown = mysql_real_escape_string($fb_info['hometown']['name']);
  $bio = mysql_real_escape_string($fb_info['bio']);
  $timezone = mysql_real_escape_string($fb_info['timezone']);
  $access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();


  $id_check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM fb_users WHERE facebook_id='$facebook_id'");
  $exist = mysql_num_rows($id_check);

  if ($exist > 0)
  {
    $update = mysql_query("UPDATE fb_users SET username='$username',name='$name',email='$email',gender='$gender',birthday='$birthday',location='$location',hometown='$hometown',bio='$bio',timezone='$timezone' WHERE facebook_id='$facebook_id'");

    $_SESSION['id'] = mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT id FROM fb_users WHERE facebook_id='$facebook_id'"), 0);

    echo "<script>window.location.replace('home.php');</script>";
  }
  else
  {
    $insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO fb_users VALUES ('0', '$date', '$facebook_id','$username','$name','$email','$gender','$birthday','$location','$hometown','$bio','$timezone','$access_token')");

    $_SESSION['id'] = mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT id FROM fb_users WHERE facebook_id='$facebook_id'"), 0);

    echo "<script>window.location.replace('presmerovani.php');</script>";
  }
} 


?>
```

**fb_config.php**

```
<?php

Facebook::$CURL_OPTS[CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER] = false;
Facebook::$CURL_OPTS[CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST] = 2;


$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => '******',
  'secret' => '***',
));

?>
```

Comment: in getLoginUrl() u need to specify a valid auth redirect URL. Second thing check what is the domain name u have set in the application setting.

Comment: Could you be more specific? I don't know, what I have to do. 
In application setting I have this: http://prntscr.com/34d3r3